# 3d and 2d subplots in plotly

Tags: python, ipython, subplot, plotly

I'm trying to produce 3d and 2d subplots on plotly.  In a simple test case, I generate two subplots, where the first has two wireframe plots, and the second has a heatmap characterizing the difference between the two 3d plots.

When I attempt to plot either the first (3d) or the second (2d) subplot without the other one, they display correctly.  But when I attempt to plot both subplots, I get the following error (offline mode in ipython):

```
Javascript error adding output!
TypeError: Cannot read property 'overlaying' of undefined
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

Here is the code I used to generate the plots:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from plotly import tools 
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
import numpy as np

init_notebook_mode()

# Creating the data
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 50)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 50)
xGrid, yGrid = np.meshgrid(y, x)
R = np.sqrt(xGrid ** 2 + yGrid ** 2)
z = np.sin(R)
z2 = np.cos(R)

line_marker = dict(color='#0066FF', width=2)
line_marker2 = dict(color='green', width=2)

scene=dict(
 xaxis=dict(
     gridcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
     zerolinecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
     showbackground=True,
     backgroundcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)'
 ),  
 yaxis=dict(
     gridcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
     zerolinecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
     showbackground=True,
     backgroundcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)'
 ),  
 zaxis=dict(
     gridcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
     zerolinecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
     showbackground=True,
     backgroundcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)'
 )
)

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=1,cols=2,specs=[[{'is_3d':True},{'is_3d':False}]])
#comment this out and subplot 2 works
for i, j, k in zip(xGrid, yGrid, z): 
    fig.append_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=i, y=j, z=k, mode='lines', line=line_marker,name='wire1'),1,1) 
for i, j, k in zip(xGrid, yGrid, z2): 
    fig.append_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=i, y=j, z=k, mode='lines', line=line_marker2,name='wire2'),1,1)

#comment this out and subplot 1 works
fig.append_trace(go.Heatmap(x=x, y=y, z=np.sqrt((z-z2)**2)),1,2) 
fig['layout'].update(title='3d with heatmap',height=600,width=1000,showlegend=False)
plot_url = iplot(fig)
```

Second question:

Assuming this can be handled, is there any way to have both subplots respond to hovermouse actions? (e.g. mouse hovering over some space in x-y on the 3d plot also highlights the corresponding box on the heatmap?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible: https://plot.ly/python/mixed-subplots/. From their example:

[image]